# How to call the Existing 5 merge module(.msm in new merge module without .msi project

Tags: windows-installer, merge-module

I have the existing 5 merge module(.msm) files I have how can I call all 5 merge modules in newly created merge module(.msm) without using the MSI project.
I know we need to merge with the MSI project only, but in my newly created merge module I do not want to use the MSI project.
In merge module project only I need to call all the existing merge module without any dependency from the MSI project.

Comment: Merge modules are designed to be merged into MSI files. I am not aware of any possibility to use them without MSI files. WiX has the feature of "include files" - snippets of WiX components that can be included in many setups. That is the closest to what you ask that I can think of. It is sort of like a C++ include file. You just include the whole content of the file in another source file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer/include/embedded a merge module from another merge module.

Merge modules can only be included in an MSI.

Comment: Hi Sir,   I have saw one of the link based on that I have created merge module project which will have 2 .msm files in the reference. Here is the link what  I have refer:  https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/mergers/

Comment: Mainly I want, How to use existing merge module in another merge module, and that  should not having any dependency to the MSI.